# Ionospheric electron density measurements

Tags: electrons, atmospheric-science, density, plasma-physics, models

I've been working on measuring total electron column density (TEC) with multi frequency GPS data. In theory, signal delay caused by TEC differences should affect the code and carrier nearly evenly in opposite magnitude. I have been recording pseudorange and phase range measurements on 2 frequencies. Here's the issue: Using L1 and L2 phaseranges  my calculated signal path TEC and it's calculated effect on the L1 signal seem correct. That is the magnitude of the delay is approximately half of the pseudorange-phaserange difference on L1. However calculating TEC from either raw dual freq pseudoranges or phase smoothed pseudoranges have a much larger result. Often much more than the actual L1 pseudorange-phaserange difference. This is over many data sets spanning many seconds of data.

I'm trying to figure out what is the real TEC density along the signal path.
I am looking for a bit of knowledge regarding these calculations. I've gotten this far reading white papers so although I've seen consistent results from a couple of ways to calculate these I'm unsure if these results are what should be expected.

addendum: I have noticed at certain times some satellites phase range TEC is much larger than the pseudo based TEC. I believe these cases are showing the addition of ionospheric refraction along with the delay value. Based on the data I suspect these satellites were low on the horizontal elevation. So this appears to be something to try to take into account. I wonder how much refraction affects the attempt to measure TEC delay? Perhaps there's no way to separate these effects from this measurement technique?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, how large are the observed timing differences?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I'm really happy to see a practically oriented question. However, I'm having some trouble understanding what it is you really want to know. Could you maybe revise the post to clarify what you're measuring, what you're computing, and what the question is?

Comment: @CuriousOne One satellite I was watching this morning would have a pseudo-phase difference around 4 meters. The calculated pseudo based delay would be around 10 to 11 meters.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the datapoint. I had absolutely no intuition for the magnitude of the effect.

Comment: Have you looked at [http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-006-0093-1](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-006-0093-1) or [http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/97RS01457/abstract](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/97RS01457/abstract)?